# How to prevent direct access to Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my bucket **policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy3451901640290",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt3451901619319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my **cors**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

All files inside my bucket must be reading accessible for everyone but only viewable through my website, Is there a simple way to deny direct access to S3?

**UPDATE**

I tried to add this to my policy:

```
"Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
```

Anyway I can access all my files outside of my website directly through S3 instead I would like something like this:

Suppose I have this file on my bucket:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket1/example.jpg
```

If a user go to that link now he/she can see that image. Instead I would like to be accessible only from my website.

Let's say on my `example.com` I have this:

```
<img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket1/example.jpg" />
```

Comment: What you are asking for is exactly what the link I provided gives you (although it's pretty easy for somebody to spoof a referer header and get around it). If you added the referer condition and you can still access the files directly then something is wrong with your bucket policy.

Comment: @MarkB CloudFront Signed URL is the right way?

Comment: @NineCattoRules a signed URL will expire. So that's probably not the right way unless you generate a signed URL request for every image in your page, every time somebody loads a page.

Comment: *"I tried but it doesn't work"* means You're Doing It Wrong, somehow.  It does work.  I'll take a guess that you also set your *objects* to `public-read`, so, yeah, just adding this to the policy won't work, because the policy isn't actually doing anything.